# Executor Service - create two single thread executors or use a thread pool of 2?

Tags: java, executorservice, executor

I have a task that runs in an endless while loop to read from a queue of numbers and checks if there is a sequence gap. Then, the main thread listens to UDP multicast and if it receives a packet, it creates and submits a runnable task to an executor service that will persist the packet to a file, then add it to the queue to be read. The persisting of packet to file and adding of packets to queue needs to be done in sequential order which is why I use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` for this task.

I instantiated two separate Executor Services `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` for these two tasks. I want to ask if it is better to instantiate two executor services as I have done, or I can achieve the same by using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);`?

I assume that since the first task is an endless while loop, it will take up one thread, then the second thread should have sequential execution of incoming tasks. Will there be any performance issues or will it not behave as I expect?

a snip shot of the code (this one currently uses threads).

```
public UDPServer(UDPChannel... udpChannels) throws IOException {
        //I had a executor service here to check the thread
        SEQUENCE_CHECKER_THREAD = new Thread(new SequenceChecker(QUEUE), "SequenceChecker");
        SEQUENCE_CHECKER_THREAD.start();

        //needs to check sequential tasks
        TASK_SCHEDULER = new TaskScheduler(BUFFER_POOL, QUEUE);
        TASK_SCHEDULER_THREAD = new Thread(TASK_SCHEDULER, "TaskScheduler");
        TASK_SCHEDULER_THREAD.start();

        SELECTOR = Selector.open();
        for (UDPChannel channel : udpChannels){
            DatagramChannel ch = channel.getCHANNEL();
            ch.register(SELECTOR, SelectionKey.OP_READ, channel);  //I am listening for clients are ready to be read
        }
        CHANNELS = udpChannels;
    }
/**
     * This is a helper method to have the "UDPServer" listen to messages in an endless loop. By iterating over the
     * selector's keys in a nested while loop, we listen to and receive data from channels that are ready to be read.
     * @throws IOException the IOException that is thrown, if UDPServer has a problem {@link #closeChannels() closing channels}
     */
    public void startReceiving() throws IOException {
        if (isTraceEnabled) LOGGER.trace(mainMarker,"Server preparing to receive...");
        running = false;
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            if (running){
                closeChannels();
                closeQueue();
                break;
            }
            try{
                if (SELECTOR.selectNow() == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
            }catch(IOException ioException){
                ioException.printStackTrace();
                LOGGER.error(ioException.getMessage());
            }

            Iterator<SelectionKey> iter = SELECTOR.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                SelectionKey key = iter.next();
                if (key.isReadable()){
                    try {
                        receiveData(key);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
        if (isTraceEnabled) LOGGER.trace(mainMarker,"PacketSink finished receiving...");
    }

    /**
     * helper method to receive data from a provided datagram channel into the byteBuffer.
     * This method then calls the decodeByteBuffer method to decode. Then , using chronicle queue's
     * appender, writes a "self-describing" message to the queue. Do <b>NOT</b> use the try-with-resources to
     * write the document. It writes in a wrong low-level format which clashes with self-describing messages
     * and causes tailer to not be able to read.
     * <p>
     *     try (final DocumentContext dc = APPENDER.writingDocument()){
     *         dc.wire().writeDocument(w -> w.write("packet").marshallable(
     *                 m->m.write("moldUdpHeader").text(moldUdpHeader.toString())
     *                         .write("byteBuffer").bytes(buffer.array())
     *         ));
     *     }catch(Exception e){
     *         e.printStackTrace();
     *     }
     *
     * @param key the SelectionKey that represents a selected channel
     * @throws IOException IOException when dealing with DatagramChannels/UDP Sockets
     */
    private void receiveData(SelectionKey key) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if (isTraceEnabled) LOGGER.trace(mainMarker,"Key: {}", key);
        DatagramChannel channel = (DatagramChannel) key.channel();
        ByteBuffer buffer;
        while((buffer = BUFFER_POOL.getBuffer()) == null){}  //while unable to get buffer, continue to poll for buffer

        buffer.clear();
        InetSocketAddress remoteAdd = (InetSocketAddress) channel.receive(buffer);
        buffer.flip();

        try {  //here is where i previously used a single threaded executor service to schedule sequential tasks
            TASK_SCHEDULER.scheduleTask(buffer, remoteAdd,((UDPChannel) key.attachment()).getChannelMarker());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.warn(e.getMessage());
        }
        if (isTraceEnabled) LOGGER.trace(mainMarker,"Server has read from key: {}", key);
    }
```

Comment: I guess you should add your code here, it is not clear what you are explaining

Comment: hello, i added some source code, i have refactored it to use threads currently instead of an executor service, but you could just assume it uses two executor services of single thread as mentioned in the question

Comment: but basically, i want to know does creating two executor services that use single thread cause performance issues? i assume it might be expensive to instantiate two different executor service objects, and could a thread pool of 2 be more performant/less expensive while still being able to meet the requirements of executing the tasks in order?

Comment: You do not need to create a thread _pool_ (i.e. an `ExecutorService`) if your UDPServer is running for the whole duration of the program. A pool is used for Thread reuse. If your task is blocking a Thread for the entire duration, you don't have to create an extra pool for it. I'd probably just stick with `new Thread` for the UDPServer and `newSingleThreadExecutor()` for the packet tasks.